# IntelliJ - File watchers: wrong output of macros

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, macros, webstorm, file-watcher

I am trying to setup a file watcher for scss files which is working on files with a filename not starting with `_`.

But if I have a file named `_file_name.scss` the output of any macros that include the filename will be `file.name.scss`.

The first `_` is removed and following ones are replaced by `.`.

Even though in the `insert macros` selection tool I can see that the output when you select a macro is correct.

Like `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$` will display `mypath/_file_name.scss` in the selection tool but then my command from this file watcher will output `mypath/file.name.scss`.

Am I missing a parameter here ?

Full configuration: 
[image]

Comment: Please post the full watcher configuration

Comment: Added a picture of the watcher config

Comment: The problem is the usage of prettier. Do you have a configuration file for prettier or you are just using the default config? By the way prettier is not compiling your sass files. Don’t you have another watcher for that?

Comment: Yeah the compiling is handle by webpack. There is a prettier config and it's working fine, vscode works fine with it, webstorm too for file not starting with `_`.

The param `COMPILE_PARTIAL=true` to add in environment variables of file watcher config as @lena suggest in his answer solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, existing file names are not changed when using similar file watcher. But files with names starting the `_` are not prettified, the *main* `.scss` that includes them is processed instead. 
To avoid this, try adding `COMPILE_PARTIAL=true` variable to your file watcher settings:

[image]

Also, make sure that **Track only root files** is off.

See the comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13459